# Alternative way of providing uninterrupted powersupply

Tags: hardware

I am building a Project where I Need to toggle between the power supplies of Adapter and a self power supply, Preferrablly an ac source which provides an UPS and stable supply without doing any harm to the board. I have seen many websites of providing a additional board to the PI, I would like to hear from the People who have used it.

Comment: Which type of raspberry are you using?

Comment: @qwerty I am using a Raspberry PI 2 Model B+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.reichelt.de/RASP-STROM-PI-2/3/index.html?&ACTION=3&LA=446&ARTICLE=161028&artnr=RASP+STROM+PI+2&SEARCH=Strom+pi+2), This will help you to provide an Unterrupted supply and can toggle between your adaptor supply and self supply(DC supply of 6V to 61V can be supplied along the board). I have personally used this board.

Cost of *Strom pi 2* is a tad high but the StromPi 2 provides up to 3A of power which will be sufficient to supply even larger devices with enough power. It also has a reset function for the Raspberry Pi, which cleverly expands the UPS function of the StromPi 2. I have used it for Raspberry PI 2 Model B.

Data Sheets and requirements are also provided in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way is to use a dumb USB battery pack. But this does not notify your Raspberry PI when there is a power loss.
You really need a proper UPS which is connected with an USB cable running `apcupsd`.